# Single model with unique intercept and slope for each observation

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to use R to generate a linear model with a unique intercept and slope for each observation - effectively, a single linear model for each observation but contained within a single lm object.

My dataset has one independent variable that is continuous (x2) and one variable that is a unique id for each observation (x1) and x1 is a factor.  If I do this

```
fit <- lm(y ~ -1 + x1 + x1*x2, data)
```

I get one intercept for each observation, but the slopes are represented differently.  There is a slope parameter for x2 and then a slope parameter for each interaction term starting with the second x1 factor.  The problem is that all the slope parameters for interaction terms are relative to the first unique value of x1.

Is there a way to formulate this such that I get a unique intercept and slope for each observation that is not relative to a baseline observation?

I get close with one intercept per observation, but for the slop

Comment: You cannot estimate two parameters per observation, unless you constrain/regularize in some fashion

Comment: Oh, wow.  Now that I read your comment, I should have known that.  Thank you.